# Libre office formatting find & replace

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I need to insert a tag at the begginning of each line in for every combination of bold/italic, which I though I could easily accomplish using the find and replace tool, but the formatting check on it simply fails. My regex is fine (as in "works as expected without the formating options"), but when I add the formatting data, it doesn't match anything, or it matches like two out of two hundred occurances. Is there any way to fix this? Or am I simply doing something wrong? Or is this just a bug I can't do anything with?

This is what the regex finds without the formatting:
[image: Regex replace without the formatting]
This is what it finds with the formatting set to italic (which should match the author of the song and nothing else)
[image: Regex replace with formatting]
And here the properties of the font used for the author line:
[image: The properties of the font]

Comment: Maybe people could make an educated guess if you showed them a test snippet and your regex ...

Comment: Added screenshots of the file, regex and font properties